# Changing to Pointer Arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm new to pointers in C and I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to work with them.

I have this piece of code with some pointer arithmetic inside a void function:

```
void function(int n, int *a, int *b){
   int *p,*q;
   q = b;
   int i;
   *b = 0;

    for (i = 1; i<n; i++)
       if(*(a+i) == *(a+i-1))
          *(b+i)=0;
       else
          *(b+i)=1;
}
```

I'm trying to change it completely to use only pointer arithmetic with no loop index variables. So far I've gotten this:

```
void function(int n, int *a, int *b){
   int *p,*q;
   q = b;
   *b = 0;

    for (p = a+1; p<a+n; p++)
       if(*a == *a-1)
          *b=0;
       else
          *b=1;
}
```

But to my understanding isn't it exactly the same as the first piece of code above? Am I missing something? Thanks for your help

Comment: `for (p = a+1; p<a+n; p++) *++b = (*p != *(p-1));`

Comment: Thank you blue pixy! I really appreciate it. These pointers are so complicated

Comment: @Ashley - Pointers are not complicated - You use them every day. On the road a sign saying `left to X` has the value `left to X` - what it points to is `x` in this case the integer. The pointer itself tells you where X is

Answer (score 2):

If you are struggling with *pointers* a bit, the short version of how to understand a *pointer* is to understand it is simply a variable that holds an *address* to something else as its *value*. Take a normal variable `int x = 5;` where `x` contains the *immediate-value* `5`.

A pointer on the other-hand, does not contain an *immediate-value*, but contains the address where an *immediate-value* (or another pointer) can be found in memory. This provides quite a bit of increased flexibility in how you use pointers. Just as you can use arithmetic on `x` (e.g. `x++;`) to increment `5` -> `6`, when you increment a *pointer* to an array, the pointer now points to the next address in the array.

So if you have declared `int a[] = {3, 5, 7, 9};`, you would have the following relationships regarding `a` among the sequential block of memory allocated as storage for `a`:

```
 a    m1  m2  m3  m4    /* points to memory locations m1 -> m4 */
    | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |   /* the zero based array indexes        */
    | 3 | 5 | 7 | 9 |   /* the values stored in m1 -> m4       */
```

You desire to eliminate working with the array indexes `0-4` and perform the same manipulations in `function` using only the memory address location information and their values. This is where *pointer-arithmetic* can be used just like array indexing to set, compare, remove values from your array. When iterating an array using a pointer, you generally will declare a pointer to use for iteration purposes *so you do not lose* the *start address* for your block of memory.

Thankfully when pointers (or arrays due to conversion) are passed as arguments to a function, the function receives a *copy* of the *pointer* and not the original address for the pointer in the calling function. You still may need to save a pointer holding the original address for the *copy*, but that just depends on what you need to do in the *function*.

If you want to re-implement the same logic in `function` incrementing pointers instead of incrementing an index `'i'`, then you will need to handle the increment of the first pointer position in both `a` and `b` when you set your default `*b=0;`. While you can simply skip over the first character in each using indexes by iterating `for (i = 1;...`, you must increment the pointers themselves if you take that approach. You can handle that within the loop by simply skipping the iteration where `a` holds its original address:

```
void functionp (int n, int *a, int *b)
{
int *p = a;  /* saved the original value of the copy */
*b = 0;

    for (; a < p + n; a++, b++)
        if (a > p)
            *b = (*a == *(a - 1)) ? 0 : 1;
        else
            continue;  /* skip first loop where 'p == a' */
}
```

Or, you can preincrement both `a` and `b` before starting the loop (e.g. `a++, b++;`) to insure your are addressing the second and first characters in `a` in your `if` statement. An example there would be:

```
void functionp (int n, int *a, int *b)
{
int *p = a;  /* saved the original value of the copy */
*b = 0;

    a++, b++;  /* increment both 'a' and 'b' */
    for (; a < p + n; a++, b++)
        *b = (*a == *(a - 1)) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Since you seem to have a fair handle on the *dereferencing* aspect of pointers to operate on the value pointed to in memory, I'll leave that to you. A short comparison example allows you to run the code without argument (or with argument not beginning with `'f'`) to see the results of your original function on the array, or providing an arguments that begins with `'f'` will call the pointer use function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function (int n, int *a, int *b);
void functionp (int n, int *a, int *b);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int a[] = {1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4};
    int i, n = sizeof a/sizeof *a;
    int b[n];

    if (argc > 1 && *argv[1] == 'f') {
        printf ("\n executing 'function'\n\n");
        function (n, a, b);
    }
    else {
        printf ("\n executing 'functionp'\n\n");
        functionp (n, a, b);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (" a[%d] : %d | b[%d] : %d\n", 
                i, a[i], i, b[i]);

    return 0;
}

void function (int n, int *a, int *b)  /* original function */
{
int i;
*b = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    if(*(a+i) == *(a+i-1))
        *(b+i)=0;
    else
        *(b+i)=1;
}

void functionp (int n, int *a, int *b) /* pointer use only function */
{
int *p = a;
*b = 0;

    a++, b++;  /* increment both 'a' and 'b' */
    for (; a < p + n; a++, b++)
        *b = (*a == *(a - 1)) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/idx2ptr f

 executing 'function'

 a[0] : 1 | b[0] : 0
 a[1] : 1 | b[1] : 0
 a[2] : 2 | b[2] : 1
 a[3] : 2 | b[3] : 0
 a[4] : 3 | b[4] : 1
 a[5] : 3 | b[5] : 0
 a[6] : 3 | b[6] : 0
 a[7] : 4 | b[7] : 1


$ ./bin/idx2ptr p

 executing 'functionp'

 a[0] : 1 | b[0] : 0
 a[1] : 1 | b[1] : 0
 a[2] : 2 | b[2] : 1
 a[3] : 2 | b[3] : 0
 a[4] : 3 | b[4] : 1
 a[5] : 3 | b[5] : 0
 a[6] : 3 | b[6] : 0
 a[7] : 4 | b[7] : 1
```

Look over the function and the example and let me know if you have any questions. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same, you have to substitute `a` with `p` in the `for` body and use the `q` pointer to modify `b`.

```
void function(int n, int *a, int *b)
{
   *b = 0;
    for (int *p = a + 1, *q = b ; p < a + n ; ++p, ++q)
    {
       if (*p == *(p - 1))
          *q = 0;
       else
          *q = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wondering the same thing... that `i` shouldn't be there?

Comment: @Ashley And Bluepixy! Right!

Answer (score 0):

Your program have some unused variables. Don't ignore the compiler's warning.

Here is what I guess you mean:

```
void function0(int n, int *a, int *b)
{
    b[0] = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if(a[i] == a[i-1])
            b[i] = 0;
        else
            b[i] = 1;
}
```

`function0()` is **syntactically** identical to

```
void function1(int n, int *a, int *b)
{
    *b = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if(*(a + i) == *(a + i - 1))
            *(b + i) = 0;
        else
            *(b + i) = 1;
}
```

which is **functionally** identical to:

```
void function2(int n, int *a, int *b)
{
    *b = 0;
    int *p, *q;
    for (p = a + 1, q = b; p < a + n; p++, q++)
        if(*p == *(p - 1))
            *q = 0;
        else
            *q = 1;
}
```