# Using pointers and arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Purpose: Write a program that finds the edges of light and dark regions.
Use pointer arithmetic. Process an input bit pattern in the following manner:

- Assign a 1 to the output bit pattern whenever two consecutive bits
  (one bit and it’s previous bit) are different.
- Assign a 0 to the output bit pattern whenever two consecutive bit
  (one bit and it’s previous bit) are the same.
- Assign 0 to the first output bit since there is no previous bit
  for the first bit.

So I'm supposed to use pointer arithmetic in the function. I can't understand this concept in the context given at all. Here's what I have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void edge(int n, int *a1, int *a2);
int main(void){
    int i;
    int input[8]={0};
    int output[8];
    /*lets user enter a code */
    printf("Enter 8 digit barcode: ");
    for( i=0; i< 8; i++)
    {
        scanf("%1d", &input[i]); 
    }    
    edge(8, input, &output);
    /*prints output */
    for( i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", output[i]); 
    }
    return 0;
}

void edge(int n, int *a1, int *a2){
    int *p;
    a2 = 0;
    for (p = a1; p <a1+n; p++)
    {  
        if (*p == *p-1)
            *a2 = 0;
        else 
            *a2 = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `edge(8, input, output);` http://stackoverflow.com/q/35532001/971127

Comment: ya, It's not running with that edit. I'm pretty sure my issue is in the function.

Comment: You need to use C bitwise operators to produce the output in `edge`. Specifically the `&` and `|` operators.

Comment: the author mixes up bits and bytes. Assignment requires bit operations while code handles int. function edge() does not fulfill the assignment and needs a re-design.